# How to get default constructor parameter using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

This kind of seemed easy to figure out but now am confused:

```
scala> class B(i:Int)
defined class B

scala> classOf[B].getDeclaredFields
res12: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array()
```

Note this:

```
scala> class C(i:Int){
     | val j = 3
     | val k = -1
     | }
defined class C

scala> classOf[C].getDeclaredFields
res15: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private final int C.j, private final int C.k)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare `i` as a `val` or a `var`, or if you make `B` a case class, then you'll see:

```
scala> classOf[B].getDeclaredFields
res1: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private final int B.i)
```

If you do neither, no method or field named `i` is generated, because it's just a constructor parameter that's never used; there is no reason it would result in a method or field existing.

Note that the Scala compiler never generates public members, only private ones. Access from outside is meant to go through the *method* named `i`.

Comment: Ah got it! I was thinking of some design and then I thought I will try it on REPL before :) great!

Comment: It'll also become a field if you use `i` inside your class, like `class B(i:Int) { def age = i } `